# Парсинг данных ics и вывод на странице

Tags: php

Подскажите как можно спарсить данные из ical - файл https://www.airbnb.com/calendar/ical/13353369.ics по ссылке и вывести на странице, чтобы можно было обрабатывать данные и при совпадении дат, подставлялся класс к div

Comment: О чем вопрос - как парсить или как выводить и "подставлять класс к див"?

Comment: Как спарсить из ics и те данные которые спарсили вывести на странице

Comment: Это два вопроса, которые между собой связаны очень отдаленно. [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: К примеру как здесь http://prntscr.com/jdoi5u, есть календарь и данные которые спарсили из ics вывести в календаре. демо https://time.ly/timely-free-calendar/#start_date=2018-05-12&view=month